# Is it alright to ask about calculator programming?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

I'm not sure which StackExchange site is specific for this, but assuming this site mostly covers Mathematics and of course, most of us should be using calculators or some sort of programming interface to do our tedious sums...

## Q. Is it alright to ask questions about programming in Math-based languages?

You might say for me to go to [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com) but the site is only for "proper programming", and I mean like "Software Development" or "Software Coding".

In case, the question is:

> ## On a Cassio Classpad, what is the correct syntax for comments?
>
> Tags: [calculator](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/calculator)
>
> In **computer** programming languages, such as C# and Visual Basic, we have comments.
>
> ```
> // This is a comment in C#
> ' This is a comment in Visual Basic
> <!-- This is a comment in HTML -->
> ```
>
> What would be the equivalent for a Cassio Classpad program?
> Of course, I could `Print` but that would display it onto the screen and make my screen cluttered with unwanted messages.

Note: Please do not answer the above question here, and no - I haven't posted it yet... Until I get the greenlight anyways.

Comment: You can have a look at questions tagged ([tag:calculator]) on the main site, to see what types of questions have been asked and how they were received.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Questions that are effectively support questions regarding the usage of any *particular* device or software are not on-topic for this site, even if the device or software is mainly or only used for mathematics.

Comment: I believe [scicomp.se] welcomes some such questions; I am not sure about your particular one though.